# Tomcat suddenly and permanently loses ability to serve particular URL (caching issue?)

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

Twice (on the same server) tomcat has suddenly, and permanently, stopped serving URLs of the form `www.example.com/foo` where `foo` is a subfolder inside a webapp rather than a webapp in itself. All subsequent requests to that URL throw 404.

No amount of restarting tomcat and/or deleting the `work` and `temp` directories seems to help - the only solution we have found is to rename the folder in the app to something else. If we create a new folder `foo` it is similarly afflicted. It's almost as if the name `foo` itself becomes toxic. The offending server has a load-balanced twin which was built at the same time and has not (yet!) suffered from this problem.

I suspect a caching issue, but aside from `work` and `temp` can find nothing else likely to contain this data. The `conf` directory is write-protected and contains no cached files.

I'm running tomcat 7.0.42 on windows server 2008r2 (patched to Dec 2013) with jre 7u40.

UPDATE:

The application was complaining about missing database credentials, which are stored in a file under the top level WEB-INF folder. Copying this file into a new WEB-INF folder under the subfolder fixes the problem.

The question now becomes: if the subfolder requires its own WEB-INF, why did it ever work? Why does renaming the broken subfolder to another name cause the credentials to be inherited from the top level WEB-INF for a limited period of time?

Curiouser and curiouser...

Comment: You sure it's definitely not the load balancer causing the problem? Are you able to bypass the load balancer and hit the affected Tomcat instance directly on port 8080 (or whatever port it happens to be running on)?

Comment: It turns out now that the problem isn't that something is going into the cache, but that something was getting removed. The only reason it was working was that it was still serving cached data. I'm blaming the application here...